# GWT not working in development mode

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea

I am trying to run a project created with GWT. In Intellij Idea I have created a Run Configuration of type GWT Configuration with the folowing:

- dev mode parameter:

  -noserver -bindAddress 127.0.0.1 -codeServerPort 9997 -war D:\projects\greensoft\trunk\out\artifacts\sd_extern_war_exploded
- server: Default

When I start it prints:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:60552', transport: 'socket'
Nov 28, 2014 12:45:31 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
Dev Mode initialized. Startup URLs: 
http://127.0.0.1:8888/chestionar.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
```

But when I start the server, this url does not work:

```
http://localhost:8080/sd-extern/chestionar.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
```

An alert appears with the error:

```
Plugin failed to connect to Development Mode server at 127.0.0.1:9997
```

Any ideas?

Thank you,
Tekin.

Comment: It looks like you are using an external server. have you tried: http://127.0.0.1:8888/chestionar.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997? Does that work?

Comment: No it doesn't. Any idea why that link appears in the console when I start the GWT configuration?

Comment: @TekinOmer Either you're not actually running in `-noserver` mode, or you just need to pass `-startupUrl http://localhost:8080/sd-extern/chestionar.html` so that it outputs the same URL as you're opening in your browser (and you can then just ask GWT DevMode to open it)

Comment: @ThomasBroyer I have added -startupUrl. Now that url appears in the console, but server still can't connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should also see a link to https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/TroubleshootingOOPHM

Maybe just try using `http://127.0.0.1:8080` instead of `http://localhost:8080`.

Comment: The icon is red, and when I click it it says: "The web and code server (127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1) is allowed to use the plugin". Using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost doesn't work either.

Comment: Then maybe doublecheck your firewall settings; maybe Windows is blocking connections on port 9997.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't add Web Facet for your IntelliJ module. You can see it in the Modules tab in the Project Structure dialog. The module should have GWT facet and Web facet under it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. I finally found the problem: the application uses another application which also has a GWT facet (which I didn't create in Idea).
I didn't think to mention the fact that there were multiple modules, so I guess the fault is mine :)